# Porting ANTLR3 to ANTLR4 symbol to token replacement

Tags: antlr, antlr4

#### What is the appropriate translation from ANTLR3 to ANTLR4 syntax?

```
tokens {
         AND,
         OR
       }
```

with ANTLR3 I used the following to replace the `&` with the token `AND`

```
and_or : '&' -> AND 
       | '|' -> OR
       ;
```

#### How do I declare this in ANTLR4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no rewrite rules in ANTLR4, so the closest you get is like this:

```
and_or
 : AND 
 | OR
 ;

AND : '&';
OR : '|';
```